# How to invoke a modal on function response in React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui

I want to invoke something like a function call inside of a response so that I can open up a modal. I'm using material ui for the modal.

[Modal](https://material-ui.com/components/modal/#SimpleModal.js)

The flow goes with something like

1. Click on a button
2. Send request
3. Get response and display message in Modal.

The modal exists as a separate component so i cannot do

```
.then( e => {
        <Modal />
       })
```

Tried including the modal hook in the same file but doesn't work like that.

```
axios
      .post(`${url}`, {
        email: email
      })
      .then(res => {
        if (res.data.type === "account not found") {
          <WarningModal />
        } else if (res.data.type === "email sent") {
          <SuccessModal />
        }
      });
```

Just want to invoke modal components on receiving response.

Comment: You are making this request inside your react component ?

Comment: Define model inside render function based on boolean value which will be handled in response of api call.

Comment: It's not clear where your axios request code is placed in your component. In any case, put it inside a function outside of your render. Call the function onClick. Then, instead of putting `<WarningModal />` etc inside your axios, change a state variable (for example `this.state.showWarningModal` which is true or false. Same for SuccessModal. Then in your render, render the modal when the corresponding state variable is true

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you want to do is this:

1. Add your `Modal` component to your component's render function. Like so:
2. Hook the `open` prop of the `Modal` component to a state, call it `openModal`. Now you have this.state.openModal.
3. On request response, do a `this.setState({openModal: true})`
4. The modal should now be opening.

You should have something like this:

```
render() => {
       return (
          ...
          <Modal open={this.state.openModal}/>
       )
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

As you may have noticed, the `Modal` component from material-ui takes an `open` prop indicating whether the modal is open or not.

So what you have to do is to put the modal somewhere in your JSX with the `open` prop set to a boolean value coming from your component's state.
And when you receive the response from your HTTP call, you toggle this boolean to true, and the modal will appear.

Answer (score 2):

Add 2 state variable for both modals and set them true in the axios call, also add the modal to the return.

```
const test = () => {
    const [showSuccessModal, setShowSuccessModal] = useState(false)
    const [showWarningModal, setShowWarningModal] = useState(false)


    axios
      .post(`${url}`, {
        email: email
      })
      .then(res => {
        if (res.data.type === "account not found") {
          setShowWarningModal(true)
        } else if (res.data.type === "email sent") {
            setShowSuccessModal(true)
        }
      });

    return (
        <div>
            <WarningModal open={showWarningModal}/>
            <SuccessModal open={showSuccessModal} />
        </div>
    )

}
```